# Concat multiple rows PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-concatenation

```
     id  |     name      |   Subject   | Lectured_Times |     Faculty                      
 3258132 | Chris Smith   | SATS1364    |     10         | Science 
 3258132 | Chris Smith   | ECTS4605    |      9         | Engineering
```

How would I go about creating the following

```
3258132  Chris Smith SATS1364, 10, Science + ECTS4605, 9,Engineering
```

where the + is just a new line. Notice how after the '+'(new line) it doesnt concat the id,name

Comment: you can use string_agg() function. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370083/concat-rows-in-postgres

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT distinct concat(id,"name",string_agg(concat(subject, Lectured_Times , Faculty), chr(10))) 
from tn 
where id = 3258132 
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above string_agg is perfect solution for this.

```
select 
    id, name, string_agg(concat(subject, Lectured_Times, Faculty), '\n')
from table
group by id, name
```